# Sort an array by occurances mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Is it possible to sort an array by occurrences?

For Example, given

```
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "60d20d342c7951852a21s53a"
            },
        "site": "www.xyz.ie",
        "A": ["mary", "jamie", "john", "mary", "mary", "john"], 
    }
```

return

```
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "60d20d342c7951852a21s53a"
            },
        "site": "www.xyz.ie",
        "A": ["mary", "jamie", "john", "mary", "mary", "john"], 
        "sorted_A" : ["mary","john","jamie"]
    }
```

I am able to get it most of the way there but I cannot figure out how to join them all back together in an array.

I have been using an aggregation pipeline

1. Starting with `$match` to find the site I want
2. Then `$unwind` on with path: `"$A"`
3. Next `$sortByCount` on `"$A"`
4. ???? I can't figure out how to group it all back together.

Here is the pipeline:

```
[
    {
        '$match': {
            'site': 'www.xyz.ie'
        }
    }, {
        '$unwind': {
            'path': '$A'
        }
    }, {
        '$sortByCount': '$A'
    }, {
        ????
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `$group` nu `_id` and `A`, get first `site` and count total elements
- `$sort` by `count` in descending order
- `$group` by only `_id` and get first `site`, and construct array of `A`

```
[
  { $match: { site: "www.xyz.ie" } },
  { $unwind: "$A" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: { _id: "$_id", A: "$A" },
      site: { $first: "$site" },
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  { $sort: { count: -1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id._id",
      site: { $first: "$site" },
      A: { $push: "$_id.A" }
    }
  }
]
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SgLDLq7tdwN)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, not the answer I am looking for though. The sorted_A should be sorted by occurrences. which addtoSet is not. "Order of the elements in the output array is unspecified." https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/

Comment: yes you are right i have updated the answer with solution.

Comment: Is there a way to keep the original A and Sorted_A separate? I have tried it here but fail to see how to flatten the A back to the way it was https://mongoplayground.net/p/pV70LBlLUHu

Comment: look at this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Gu9n772dpLU).